# How do I change default terminal for executing .desktop files?

Tags: command-line, bash, .desktop, vim

I've been trying to execute vim with alacritty as default. I have alacritty set as my default terminal emulator already, and in my vim.desktop I changed `exec=vim %F` with `exec=alacritty -e vim %F`. The problem is that when I open a file it first executes the command in gnome terminal and then launches vim in alacritty, the thing is that the gnome terminal stays open. I have also tried creating an script:

```
#!/bin/bash
alacritty -e vim & disown | exit
```

this does not work at all. I don't know what else to do and I cant find anything online. Thanks in advance!

Is it possible to change the default terminal that runs the `Exec=` command? so that just by writing `Exec=vim %F` would run it in alacritty

Comment: Do you have `Terminal=True` in your `vim.desktop`?

Comment: yes, what does exactly `Terminal=` do? If I put `Terminal=alacritty` it will launch in alacritty?

Comment: It starts the command in the default terminal (for some value of "default"). It only supports `true` or `false`.

Comment: as easy as that... I feel a complete noob, thank you very much! `Terminal=false` does exactly what I want it to do. Should I delete the question? now I feel that is kind of a stupid question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

muru helped me clarify what was going on, thank you! The problem was that my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Comment[es]=Edita archivos de texto
TryExec=vim
Exec=alacritty -e vim %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Keywords=Text;editor;
Icon=gvim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
```

Had the argument `Terminal=true`. What this does is that it executes the `Exec=` command in a terminal, opening a terminal to do so. If you set `Terminal=false` this will prevent any terminal from opening and it will just execute the command without opening the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I've posted [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642886) to a similar question on U&L

TL;DR - `prepend_terminal_to_vector()` prefers `gnome-terminal` the most. Create a wrapper script `/usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal` which invokes the actual terminal emulator based on what `$#` `$@` it receives.

Comment: oops this answer applies to the question TITLE only, not the question's BODY...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this does not work sometimes, I don't know what is controlling what terminal emulator is used when you open vim.

I just found another work-around for this problem: create a symlink named `xterm` in your `$PATH` to your own terminal emulator. I can not guarantee this works for everyone though.

The advantage of this work-around is you don't need to change any desktop entry files. All .desktop with `Terminal=true` will use the new terminal emulator.

---

When trying to exec a desktop entry with `exo-open` (similar to `xdg-open`, from xfce), there is a warning message

```
sh: line 0: exec: xterm: not found
```

So I guess `xterm` is hard-coded in the program to open .desktop files.
Then I tried to make this symlink

```
ln -s /usr/bin/st ~/.local/bin/xterm
```

and it works perfectly.

However the actual command spawned is probably based on `xterm`'s arguments, so only the terminal emulators which use the same argument to specify the start-up command works. One counter example is `termite`, since it requires the whole command to be quoted in the `-e` option.