# Why is Ubuntu 22 always launching apps with gnome-terminal or xterm, even if an alternative is configured?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, kitty-terminal

I want to switch to a new editor - LunarVim - and also to a new terminal that supports font ligatures - Kitty. Both installed globally on my system. I enabled it as the default terminal application using the following methods:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/local/bin/kitty
```

... to make it the default for the current user and

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/kitty 50
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

... to make it the default for x-terminal-emulator on the system. (tried it both with sudo and without)

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> it opens a `Kitty` terminal, so far so good.

I also added a `.desktop` file for LunarVim and added LunarVim as the default `editor` and default app for opening text files. I can confirm that this worked, I see the desktop entry in the launcher and text files open with LunarVim.

The problem is ... **LunarVim always opens in gnome-terminal**. When I click on the icon in the app launcher, it opens in gnome-terminal. When I click on a txt file in the file explorer, it opens the gnome-terminal. I just want to understand **why is this happening?**

I even tried to remove `gnome-terminal`. I will **always** install `xterm` instead and then lunarvim will **always** be opened with `xterm`. When I try to remove `xterm`, it will automagically install `gnome-terminal` again ...

It would be fantastic if anyone could enlighten me, I already literally spent hours for the simple task of installing a terminal in Ubuntu.

Just for completeness, here is the desktop file for `lvim`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LunarVim
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=An IDE layer for Neovim with sane defaults. Completely free and community driven.
TryExec=lvim
Exec=lvim %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Keywords=Text;editor;
Icon=/opt/lunarvim/lvim/utils/desktop/64x64/lvim.svg
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
```

Comment: There's some relevant info in this previous Q&A [How do I change default terminal for executing .desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238105/how-do-i-change-default-terminal-for-executing-desktop-files) and more detail in U&L [How to specify which terminal is used by gtk-launch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333661/how-to-specify-which-terminal-is-used-by-gtk-launch) - unfortunately I don't have a gnome-based system to explore the suggested solutions at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gnome Shell, there is no way of changing the terminal emulator to be used when a `desktop` launcher specifies `Terminal=true`. There is a way, though:

1. Explicitly launch the terminal emulator (e.g. `kitty`) and have it load the terminal application, e.g., `kitty lvim`.
2. Make sure `lvim` keeps having its own icon in the taskbar, separate from the icon of regular instances of `kitty`.

   a. have your terminal adopt a specific window class using a command line option, e.g., `--class lunarvim` in case of `kitty` terminal emulator.

   b. Add a statement `StartupWMClass=lunarvim` to the launcher.

Your `.desktop` launcher becomes:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LunarVim
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=An IDE layer for Neovim with sane defaults. Completely free and community driven.
TryExec=lvim
Exec=kitty --class lunarvim lvim %F
StartupWMClass=lunarvim
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=Text;editor;
Icon=/opt/lunarvim/lvim/utils/desktop/64x64/lvim.svg
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked! I had to change two things tho. If I use `kitty --class lvim %F` then it will just open Kitty, not Lunarvim, because `lvim` becomes the value for the `--class` parameter. And I'm not sure about this next part but after some trying around I got it to work when using a different `StartupWMClass` that is the same as the `--class` parameter. `Exec=kitty --class lunarvim lvim %F` and `StartupWMClass=lunarvim`
If I use your proposed values, LunarVim will start in Kitty correctly, but without an Icon and I can't lock it on the panel.

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I realized it, but then forgot to change it here: after `lvim` as class, also the command itself, `lvim` must follow (can be the same). I corrected the answer now. If it worked, then of course I'd appreciate if you could "accept"  the answer: click the checkmark next to the answer. This hints other users a usefull answer can be found here.

Comment: Yea of course, just took me a while to edit my comment ;) I hope it's okay if I edited the answer to include the `StartupWMClass` that worked for me.

Comment: I see, thank again. Actually, I see I messed up in my answer: I wrote `kitty` as class where I should have written `lvim`. Good you were able to see and handle that. I now fully corrected this, and in the example, I used your suggestion `lunarvim`. It gives the benefit that there is no confusion between the class name and the command.